# How do I hash two blocks of data with HashAlgorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hash

I need to hash a password with salt in C#. Salt is obtained from one source and is of type `byte[]`, password is obtained from another source and is of type `String`.

Computing a hash of one block is quite easy - just call [`HashAlgorithm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx).ComputeHash() and it's done, but how do I compute a hash of two blocks without first building their concatenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock` and then use the `Hash` property.

Comment: I'm confused about the outbutBuffer parameter to `TransformBlock` - why do we need to copy the data?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into the [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`TransformFinalBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx) methods.

The latter MSDN link exemplifies use of both with a code sample that is potentially to much to post here.